# ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 443) for discord bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am experimenting with making a discord bot using the discord API and python. When I run my code however, I get this really long error message. I have tried restarting my computer, but it didn't help. I am using the latest version of Python and the discord module, and I am on MacOS Big Sur 11.3.

Here is my code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('y!hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run('token')
```

And here is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 969, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1056, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1041, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 955, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 502, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 537, in _sock_connect_cb
    raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 443)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    client.run('token')
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 192, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 520, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1051, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1020, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 975, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 443)]
```

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this? It seems as if python cannot connect to something, but I don't know how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Is the computer you're running the bot on connected to the internet? It looks like he uses the internal loopback interface `127.0.0.1` instead of an actual internet connection, and hence can't connect to discord. Is maybe the firewall blocking access?

Comment: Yes, the computer is connected to WiFi. I don't know whether the firewall is blocking or not, but do you know how to manually set the internet connection?

Comment: try [pinging](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1020983) discord.com

Comment: I tried that, and it is able to connect. @Ceres

Comment: @itzFlubby do you know how to manually set the connection?

Comment: No I do not tbh. You would have to find the specific code to change in the source-code of asyncio. But others suggested that they have the same error on MacOS. Maybe try a different python and asyncio version?

Comment: @itzFlubby how would i change my asyncio version